# Install MS Access DAO Primary Interop Assembly for Use with PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, ms-access, nuget, ms-office, gac

I am trying to automate Microsoft Access 2016 with PowerShell, but I appear to be missing an Office Primary Interop Assembly called `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao`. I've tried a few approaches in PowerShell, and these are the errors that I get:

```
PS > $app.Application.OpenCurrentDatabase()
The following exception occurred while retrieving member "Application": "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At line:1 char:1
+ $app.Application.OpenCurrentDatabase()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember

PS > Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao"
Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Please note the difference in version (15.0.0.0 vs 12.0.0.0).

The only version of Office that I have installed on this machine is Office 2016 via Office 365 download. I have run `gacutil /l` from a Visual Studio Command Prompt, and I see that the other Office PIAs, version 15.0.0.0, are installed.

[According to the NuGet Web site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao/15.0.4420.1017), I could download the assembly via NuGet Package Manager Console, if I were working on a Visual Studio Solution, but I cannot install the assembly with PowerShell:

```
PS > Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

My questions are:

1. How can I install `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao` to the GAC
   so I can reference it in PowerShell scripts?
2. If nuget.org is listed as a `PackageSource` in PowerShell, why can't I use the `Install-Package` command to install this assembly?
3. Why did this assembly not get installed with Office 2016/365?

The accepted answer will provide at least a solution to my first question - How can I install `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao` to the GAC so I can reference it in PowerShell scripts?

Comment: Depending on the details of precisely how your Office 2016 was installed, you may need to separately install the stand-alone MSI version of the Access Database Engine. See [this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2874601/can-t-use-the-access-odbc-driver-or-oledb-provider-outside-office-click-to-run-applications) for details.

Comment: Rather than adding the assembly by the partial name, what happens when you use the full name?

Comment: @BenH When I run the command `PS > Add-Type("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")`, I get the error `A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods` .

Comment: @GordThompson Some sources I'm reading suggest that the name may have changed to something like `Microsoft Office 15.0 Access Database Engine Object Library` . These are posts on fixing references in C# projects rather than Powershell.